# pfSense 2.0RC Webservers LoadBalancing

Tags: load-balancing, pfsense

Hy,

I Recently installed pfSense 2.0RC and i tried to Set an Loadbalancing,

I Added the IP Pools:
192.168.1.10:80 -> webserver 1
192.168.1.100:80 -> webserver 2

And Added an Virtual Server IP:
192.168.1.200:80 -> Virtual IP

But when i trying to see http://192.168.1.200/ The Ip Address do no respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're redirecting back out the same interface with the same subnet as a source, you must use manual outbound NAT to translate the source of the requests from LB->server to the firewall's IP. You're breaking the TCP connection doing it that way without NAT (it replies direct back to the source).

Not enough info there to tell for sure that's what you're doing, but it definitely sounds like it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, all I did was add a rule in the firewall and the problem was solved.